# Python breaking a single list into multiple sublists

Tags: python, list

In python I want to take a list and break it into a list of lists.
If I have a list that is 20 numbers long, I want to turn it into a list of two lists, each 5 numbers long.

Input

`nums = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]`

Output

`new_nums = [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12, 13, 14], [15, 16, 17, 18, 19]]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
nums = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
result = [nums[x:x+5] for x in range(0, len(nums), 5)]
print(result)
#Output:
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12, 13, 14], [15, 16, 17, 18, 19]]
```